# React-Native Geolocation of other devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native, geolocation

I know React-Native has support for Geolocation, but what I need is for people to see my geolocation. Like they download the app and see where my phone is. Not theirs - mine. Pretty much an app that shows where I am and where people can find me. Is that possible?

Edit: I need this to be realtime. So a person can download my app and watch my every step.

Comment: Do you want to update your own location with the same app?

Comment: @TimH I wanted it to be realtime

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your usecase.

case 1)

You want to keep track of your own location within the same App. Then react-native shouldn't be your choice. You would need to update your location even in background mode, but this is currently not possible.

case 2)

You track your own location with a native app/or something else and you use react-native just to allow people to "follow you". Then react-native would be sufficient. You just need to send your current location from a server to your mobile app. Inside your react-native app you then need to display your current position. Therefore you could use [react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The taxi apps allow you to see the driver. Is that only possible because their app is open all the time?

Comment: It is possible with NATIVE iOS/Android Apps. But with react-native you will only receive location updates, if your App is in foreground.

Comment: You mean like a service?

Comment: Yes a background service would be needed to update the location, but it‘s currently not supported.

Comment: Would like a firebase be a solution? The hosting phone would send out pushes to all subscribed users and they would update based on these push messages? Or the firebase realtime db?

Comment: I‘m not a Firebase expert, but theoretically it should work that way